# How to convert LSTM model to linear regression with keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, time-series, lstm

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(512, input_shape=(None, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(LSTM(512, input_shape=(None, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=16, verbose=2)
p = model.predict(x_test)
```

I have this code and predict model `p`. I want to convert `p` of time series to a linear regression model.

`Time series p -> linear regression model.`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean convert to a linear regression model?

Comment: Literally, I would like to change the time series model to the linear regression model.

Comment: Then you would need to import some library that has a linear regression model (like scikit-learn) and then train this model in your data. I don't see what else you are asking. Doesn't seem to be a programming problem at all.